# How to trigger pressing of key along with shift key in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, keypress

Ok, before you mark this as a duplicate, read the title.

I know that you can do this:

```
var triggerevent = jQuery.Event("keypress");
triggerevent.which = 52; // 4
$("#inputfield").trigger(triggerevent);
```

But what if I wanted to trigger the pressing of the '$' sign for example? You can't do that without pressing shift beforehand.

How is that possible?

Comment: Get the id of the key  and use `e.shiftKey`:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468644/click-to-replace-value-shift-click-to-append-value-using-jquery/11468883#11468883

Comment: @Simon could you put that in an answer?

Comment: It says: "Trivial answer converted to comment" ...

Comment: Anyway I may have misread your question, you don't want to register the physical keypress along with shift, but trigger a shift+keypress in jQuery?

Comment: @Simon Yes like writing `$`: shift + 4, I don't know exactly what this falls under

Comment: Before I try to give a definitive answer: What is your aim here? Why do you have to trigger the key pressing instead of calling the trigger functions directly or just inserting the value?

Comment: @Simon I have to simulate the keypress, so the program can pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var triggerevent = jQuery.Event("keypress");
triggerevent.which = 36; // $

$("#textarea").on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(!e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
        var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which); // $
        this.value = c;
    }
}).trigger(triggerevent);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGdUf/9/)

**Update:** insert character programmatically, check if physical keypress occurred

**Update 2:** removed the whole shiftKey thing, because not of importance anymore

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/26ru6/, inspect the event object which I log to the console, you'll see that "shiftKey" is a simple property which the plugin reads out (like in the link from my first comment), so no magic there.

Comment: Then why doesn't this work: http://jsfiddle.net/rGdUf/1/ ? It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: I don' understand, it does work, the event gets triggered, what do you expect it to do besides that?

Comment: Shouldn't it also insert it into the textarea as well? I don't know.

Comment: Since it is your "custom" event it does not execute the actual inserting of a character, if you open the console in the fiddle and type a character into the textarea you'll see a difference in the event objects, the event fired on keypress has a property "originalEvent" which represents the before mentioned physical pressing of a key... you cannot simulate that (see [trigger keypress events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery)). I thought you just wanted to trigger the event so a plugin or external code can grab it?

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyway. Still found a way around my original problem. Marking as accepted right now.

Comment: Yeah forgot that, you know, when pressing shift+4 another keycode than 52 is registered, maybe we should just go for that...

Comment: Well shift+4 gets me 231 on my keyboard, thought it would get you an $, just log the event in my fiddle, by typing your $ you'll get the keycode ;).

Answer (score 0):

since the event object in jQuery is derived from the native DOM event, you can use those attributes to check which combination has been pressed.

[DOM W3 Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MouseEvent-ctrlKey) (Check the attributes section)